# Convert Decimal to Time

Tags: parsing, time, decimal, elixir

I am new to elixir and I am trying to find tome tutorials/documentation about parsing decimal to string time. I also need to get the number of the week so I can convert it to `YYYY-WW`

This is my request body:

```
%{"time" => 1_481_875_162}
```

Inspecting it gives me:

```
IO.inspect data["time"]
#Decimal<1481875172>
```

Comment: What is "decimal time" here? Can you give an example of the input you have and output expected?

Comment: I made edit....

Comment: Is that the Unix timestamp? Try this after installing `timex`: `data["time"] |> Decimal.to_integer |> Timex.from_unix |> Timex.format!("{YYYY}-{Wiso}")`.

Comment: Perfect It works :) !! Thank you very much

Comment: Hey @Dogbert you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `timex`, this can be done as follows:

Convert the Decimal to an Integer using `Decimal.to_integer/1`
Convert the Integer to a DateTime using `Timex.from_unix/1`
Convert the DateTime to a String formatted the way you want with `Timex.format!/2`

Since your Decimal is in `data["time"]`, the whole thing would be:

```
data["time"]
|> Decimal.to_integer
|> Timex.from_unix
|> Timex.format!("{YYYY}-{Wiso}")
```

Note that I've used the ISO Week Number. Timex also supports other types of week numbers which you can read about [here](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Format.DateTime.Formatters.Default.html#module-list-of-all-directives).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Elixir's built-in [`DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html) module to convert `timestamps` into Dates using the [`from_unix!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_unix!/2) method (but it currently does not provide a method to get the week number):

```
iex(1)> DateTime.from_unix!(1_481_875_162)           
# => %DateTime{calendar: Calendar.ISO, day: 16, hour: 7, microsecond: {0, 0}, minute: 59, month: 12, second: 22, std_offset: 0, time_zone: "Etc/UTC", utc_offset: 0, year: 2016, zone_abbr: "UTC"}
```